# Composition of polynomial-bounded function

Tags: real-analysis, computational-complexity, formal-languages

A function $f: \{ 0,1 \}^* \rightarrow \{ 0,1 \}^*$ is called **polynomial bounded** if there exists a polynomial $p(n)$ such that $|f(x)| \leq p(|x|)$ for all $x \in \{  0,1\}^*$. Here, $| x |$ means the length of $x$.

$\{0,1\}^*$ is the set of bit-strings of any size. For instance, $w_1=1101,w_2=111111101 \in \{0,1\}^*$. The length of a bit-string is defined as its number of bits. In the previous example, $|w_1|=4$ and $|w_2|=9$.

The aim is to prove that the composition of two polynomial bounded functions $f,g$ is also a polynomial bounded function.

Any hint on how the polynomial I am looking for looks like?

Comment: What is $\{0,1\}^*?$

Comment: @zhw. $\{0,1\}^*$ are bit-strings of any size.

Comment: Never heard of it. Please include this definition, as well as the definition of "length", in the statement.

Comment: @zhw. It is just notation, world-wide used in applied mathematics fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I don't know anything, but it seems to me that if $f,g$ are polynomially bounded, then there are *strictly increasing* polynomials $p,q$ on $[1,\infty)$ such that

$$|f(x)|\le p(|x|), |g(x)|\le q(|x|).$$

It follows that

$$|g(f(x))| \le q(|f(x)|)\le q(p(|x|)).$$

We used the fact that $q$ is increasing on $[1,\infty)$ to get the expression on the right. Since the composition of polynomials is a polynomial, $g\circ f$ is polynomially bounded.

Comment: This is what I attempted to do, but I am not really sure how to prove that there are such a strictly incrasing polynomials.

Comment: Suppose $|f(x)|\le p(|x|),$ where $p(t)= a_nt^n + \cdots + a_1t+a_0.$ Then for $t\ge1,$

$$p(t) \le |a_n|t^n + \cdots + |a_1|t+|a_0|.$$

The polynomial on the right is strictly increasing on $[1,\infty).$

Comment: Awesome, completily right.